# How to convert a ruby lambda to a reusable library method

Tags: ruby

I have a method in a chef recipe like so

```
overwrite_properties = lambda do |tmpl_path, params|
  attrs = {}
  File.read(tmpl_path).split("\n").map do |line|
  line = line.sub(/#.*$/, '').strip
  j, v = line.split(/\s*=\s*/, 2)
  attrs[j] = v if j
  end
  params.each {|j,v| v.nil? ? attrs.delete(j) : attrs[j] = v }
  attrs.map {|j,v| "#{j}=#{v}\n" }.sort.join
end
```

which is called like so

```
overwrite_properties.call("#{server_home}/config.orig/#{fname}", params)
```

My question is how can I convert this to a reusable function to be called from another module?

eg.

```
module HelperMod
    def self.overwrite_properties(&block)
       //etc
    end
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple - a lambda is an anonymous function (function with no name). You can convert this to a function within a module like so:

```
module HelperMod
  def self.overwrite_properties(tmpl_path, params)
    attrs = {}
    File.read(tmpl_path).split("\n").map do |line|
      line = line.sub(/#.*$/, '').strip
      j, v = line.split(/\s*=\s*/, 2)
      attrs[j] = v if j
    end
    params.each {|j,v| v.nil? ? attrs.delete(j) : attrs[j] = v }
    attrs.map {|j,v| "#{j}=#{v}\n" }.sort.join
  end
end

HelperMod.overwrite_properties("#{server_home}/config.orig/#{fname}", params)
```

Comment: I would use `.` instead of `::` for method invocation, i.e. `HelperMod.overwrite_properties(...)`